# Google vision APIs : How to detect the image is painting image or real picture?

Tags: java, google-cloud-vision

I have an issue with detecting image whether it is painting image or real picture taken. I have checked Google Vision REST-APIs documentation, it seems that it does not mention for that.

Appreciate if you can share algorithm how to detect it.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time, you can search into webEntities array of the JSON response. I tried with your seconde picture and got the following result :

```
"webEntities": [
  {
    "entityId": "/m/068jd",
    "score": 0.71919,
    "description": "Photograph"
  },
  {
    "entityId": "/m/04dtx9",
    "score": 0.71809,
    "description": "Flickr"
  },
  {
    "entityId": "/m/07glzq",
    "score": 0.71192,
    "description": "Sketch"
  },
  {
    "entityId": "/m/0k0pj",
    "score": 0.64715505,
    "description": "Nose"
  },
  {
    "entityId": "/m/01kr8f",
    "score": 0.41121,
    "description": "Illustration"
  },
  {
    "entityId": "/m/03c51f4",
    "score": 0.39885,
    "description": "Tagged"
  },
  {
    "entityId": "/m/01dv4h",
    "score": 0.37724,
    "description": "Portrait"
  },
  {
    "entityId": "/m/02csf",
    "score": 0.37219,
    "description": "Drawing"
  },
  {
    "entityId": "/m/0jjw",
    "score": 0.36841,
    "description": "Art"
  },
  {
    "entityId": "/m/03b19x",
    "score": 0.36128,
    "description": "Digital painting"
  },
  {
    "entityId": "/m/0mfx0",
    "score": 0.31653,
    "description": "Doodle"
  },
```

I think there is no trivial way to do it except for searching in these tags for words like "paint","drawing","sketch"..

Comment: I agree with that the values are various and hard to determine it is accept as painting or others.... I think Google Vision should extend algorithm to support this issue. For my case, I need to detect the image is standard and real picture as passport photo and painting images are not allowed somehow